# Merge / Join SQL Select Queries

Tags: sql, select, join, merge

I am struggling  with combining the below Select Statments, I know I could cheat and add some fake columns in and then use Union, but I want to do this correctly. 
Once I have them joined, I will be putting the Statment in to a XML file for use with Word and CRM4.

```
SELECT BILLTO_NAME, 
       BILLTO_LINE1, 
       BILLTO_LINE2, 
       BILLTO_LINE3, 
       BILLTO_CITY, 
       BILLTO_COUNTRY, 
       BILLTO_POSTALCODE, 
       ORDERNUMBER, 
       REQUESTDELIVERYBY, 
       MODIFIEDON, 
       SHIPTO_NAME, 
       SHIPTO_LINE1, 
       SHIPTO_LINE2, 
       SHIPTO_LINE3, 
       SHIPTO_CITY, 
       SHIPTO_STATEORPROVINCE, 
       SHIPTO_COUNTRY, 
       SHIPTO_POSTALCODE, 
       CREATEDBY 
FROM   SALESORDERBASE 



SELECT QUANTITY, 
       DESCRIPTION 
FROM   SALESORDERDETAILBASE 

SELECT NEW_ORDERNOTES, 
       NEW_NOTES 
FROM   SALESORDEREXTENSIONBASE
```

They all have the common column of SalesOrderID, which I need to add in somewhere as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) on the tables:

```
SELECT ob.SalesOrderID 
       ob.BILLTO_NAME, 
       ob.BILLTO_LINE1, 
       ob.BILLTO_LINE2, 
       ob.BILLTO_LINE3, 
       ob.BILLTO_CITY, 
       ob.BILLTO_COUNTRY, 
       ob.BILLTO_POSTALCODE, 
       ob.ORDERNUMBER, 
       ob.REQUESTDELIVERYBY, 
       ob.MODIFIEDON, 
       ob.SHIPTO_NAME, 
       ob.SHIPTO_LINE1, 
       ob.SHIPTO_LINE2, 
       ob.SHIPTO_LINE3, 
       ob.SHIPTO_CITY, 
       ob.SHIPTO_STATEORPROVINCE, 
       ob.SHIPTO_COUNTRY, 
       ob.SHIPTO_POSTALCODE, 
       ob.CREATEDBY,
       od.QUANTITY,
       od.DESCRIPTION,
       oe.NEW_ORDERNOTES,
       oe.NEW_NOTES
FROM   SALESORDERBASE ob
LEFT JOIN SALESORDERDETAILBASE od
    on ob.SalesOrderID = od.SalesOrderID
LEFT JOIN SALESORDEREXTENSIONBASE oe
    on ob.SalesOrderID = oe.SalesOrderID
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, I Thought it was a join I needed but wasnt to sure, I have a slight issues with the fact the SalesOrderBase and the SalesOrderDetailBase both have a Description column in, I guess I could just take one out. Does anyone have any suggestions for SQL books I could read up on? Ry

Comment: @RyanKeen all you need to do is provide an alias with different name for those fields. Then you should have no issues returning data from both columns. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column that identifies the relationship is called id on all three tables, you can do this:

```
 SELECT sob.BILLTO_NAME, 
   sob.BILLTO_LINE1, 
   sob.BILLTO_LINE2, 
   sob.BILLTO_LINE3, 
   sob.BILLTO_CITY, 
   sob.BILLTO_COUNTRY, 
   sob.BILLTO_POSTALCODE, 
   sob.ORDERNUMBER, 
   sob.REQUESTDELIVERYBY, 
   sob.MODIFIEDON, 
   sob.SHIPTO_NAME, 
   sob.SHIPTO_LINE1, 
   sob.SHIPTO_LINE2, 
   sob.SHIPTO_LINE3, 
   sob.SHIPTO_CITY, 
   sob.SHIPTO_STATEORPROVINCE, 
   sob.SHIPTO_COUNTRY, 
   sob.SHIPTO_POSTALCODE, 
   sob.CREATEDBY, 
   sodb.QUANTITY, 
   sodb.DESCRIPTION,
   soeb.NEW_ORDERNOTES, 
   soeb.NEW_NOTES 
 From SalesOrderBase sob
 JOIN SalesOrderDetailBase sodb
   ON sob.id = sodb.SalesOrderID
 JOIN SalesOrderExtensionBase soeb
   ON sob.id = soeb.SalesOrderID
```

You can think of JOINing as slamming together rows side-by-side, whereas UNIONing is slamming together rows one on top of the other. UNIONS require that the columns be the same and JOINs require that there is a relationship of some kind between each row.

EDIT - The OP provided more details